# WOW.js animated start without need to reveal

Tags: javascript, jquery, wow.js

Hi how can we make the wow.js to start all the animation even the element is still not reveal?

http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

Comment: what exactly you want to do with WOW.js , Once the page is scrolled the script gets executed and the animations popup.

Comment: Hi Ben, yes the animation is only executed when the page is scroll and the element is inside the viewport. But what I try to achieve is, the animation will be carry on once page load even the element is still not visible or not scroll.

Comment: you want the animation to execute when its not visible in the view port?

Comment: Sounds like you don't need WOW.js at all in that case. WOW.js triggers animations on elements when they scroll into view. You could just use CSS animations without WOW.js to achieve the effect that you're after.

Comment: Yes that is the thing.

Comment: Hi we use the wow.js as we need the function of the delay and also animation duration parameter.

Comment: In that case, unless I'm misunderstanding your requirements, you could definitely ditch WOW.js and just use the underlying Animate.css library that WOW.js relies upon. You can then use the standard CSS properties `animation-delay` and `animation-duration` rather than relying upon WOW.js.

Comment: Hi almcd, Thanks! I got what you mean, will work by add a few classes for each different delay and duration then will add those classes in the animated element.